# Group list of object by an attribute and set other remaining attribute to different object list : Java 8 stream and Lambdas

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Very new to Java8 stream/Lambdas. I need to group a list of Student objects using an attribute(Id) then create object(StudentSubject) based on the grouped Student attributes. For example I have following classes:

```
class Student{
        int id;
        String name;
        String subject;
        int score;

        public Student(int id, String name, String subject, int score) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.subject = subject;
            this.score = score;
        }
}


class StudentSubject {
            String name;
            List<Result> results;
    }   



  class Result {
            String subjectName;
            int score;
    //getter setters
    }
```

So for following input :

```
id,name,subject,score  
1,John,Math,80
1,John,Physics,65
2,Thomas,Computer,55
2,Thomas,Biology,70
```

The result output should be `List<StudentSubject>` with attributes set from the `List<Student>`. Say something as:

```
1=[
            name = 'John'
            Result{subject='Math', score=80}, 
            Result{subject='Physics', score=65}, 
        ]
2=[
            name = 'Thomas'
            Result{subject='Computer', score=55}, 
            Result{subject='Biology', score=70}, 
        ]
```

How do I grouping by Id first then set attributes to Result and StudentSubject?

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<Student> studentList = Lists.newArrayList();
            studentList.add(new Student(1,"John","Math",80));
            studentList.add(new Student(1,"John","Physics",65));
            studentList.add(new Student(2,"Thomas","Computer",55));
            studentList.add(new Student(2,"Thomas","Biology",70));

// group by Id             studentList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getId));
//set result list
List<Result> resultList = studentList.stream().map(s -> {
            Result result = new Result();
            result.setSubjectName(s.getSubject());
            result.setScore(s.getScore());
            return result;

        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/using-lambda-expression-sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result should be `List<StudentSubject>` in your case you can use this way :

```
List<StudentSubject> resultList = studentList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getId)) // until this point group by Id
        .entrySet()                                     // for each entry
        .stream()                                        
        .map(s -> new StudentSubject(                   // create a new StudentSubject
                s.getValue().get(0).getName(),          // you can use just the name of first element
                s.getValue().stream()                   // with a list of Result
                        .map(r -> new Result(r.getSubject(), r.getScore()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());                 // then collect every thing as a List
```

Outputs

```
StudentSubject{name='John', results=[Result{subjectName='Math', score=80}, Result{subjectName='Physics', score=65}]}
StudentSubject{name='Thomas', results=[Result{subjectName='Computer', score=55}, Result{subjectName='Biology', score=70}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is first a group-by operation, followed by a mapper that converts student objects to the corresponding result (just as in your function):

```
Map<String, List<Result>> resultList = studentList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getName, Collectors.mapping(s -> {
            Result result = new Result();
            result.setSubjectName(s.getSubject());
            result.setScore(s.getScore());
            return result;

        }, Collectors.toList())));
```

Which produces (slightly different `toString` implementation):

```
{Thomas=[Result [subjectName=Computer, score=55], 
         Result [subjectName=Biology, score=70]], 
 John=[Result [subjectName=Math, score=80], 
       Result [subjectName=Physics, score=65]]
}
```

Comment: the StudentSubject class may contain other attributes besides names. So how to I get the List of  StudentSubject with the attributes set?

Comment: You need to group students by id, not name, and produce StudentSubject objects.

Comment: The best way to do that would be deciding what makes a student object unique, then overriding **both** `Object#equals` and `Object#hashCode` in Student. With that, you can replace `Student::getName` with `Function.identity()` (or `s -> s`). The entire student object will be the key in the resulting map